# Multiple inputs with same name

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, user-interface

I have form, in it user can duplicate input forms, and I have a trouble with a radio buttons.
When I trying to use:

```
$('form').serialize();
```

In Chrome Dev Tools

I've got:

```
"text-field%5B%5D=%D0%98%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2+%D0%98%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD+%D0%98%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87&text-h-alignment%5B%5D=42&text-v-alignment%5B%5D=42&text-field%5B%5D=(000)+000+00+00&text-alignment%5B%5D=center& text-h-alignment%5B%5D=42&text-v-alignment%5B%5D=42"
```

As you can see, radio buttons are not in "array", it's an unique variable.
But I use the "[]" symbols at the end of variable name.

Here is my HTML:

```html
<form>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-btn">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Шаблон <span class="caret"></span>
          </button>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#" onclick="$(this).closest('.input-group').find('input[type=text]').val('Иванов Иван Иванович');">Имя</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" onclick="$(this).closest('.input-group').find('input[type=text]').val('(000) 000 00 00');">Телефон</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" onclick="$(this).closest('.input-group').find('input[type=text]').val('email@example.com');">E-mail</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" onclick="$(this).closest('.input-group').find('input[type=text]').val('г. Город, ул. Улица 1');">Адрес</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" onclick="$(this).closest('.input-group').find('input[type=text]').val('example.com');">Сайт</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="text-field[]">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
      <label class="btn btn-default active">
        <input type="radio" checked="checked" name="text-alignment[]" value="left"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      </label>
      <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input type="radio" name="text-alignment[]" value="center"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-center" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      </label>
      <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input type="radio" name="text-alignment[]" value="right"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      </label>
    </div>

    <div class="input-group spinner padding-15 pull-left">
      <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left" aria-hidden="true"></span></span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" value="42" name="text-h-alignment[]">
      <div class="input-group-btn-vertical">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></i></button>
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></i></button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="input-group spinner padding-15 pull-left">
      <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up" aria-hidden="true"></span></span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" value="42" name="text-v-alignment[]">
      <div class="input-group-btn-vertical">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></i>
        </button>
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></i>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="row margin-top-15">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <a href="#" class="color-green" onclick="$(this).closest('.container-fluid').find('.row:eq(0)').clone().prependTo($(this).closest('.container-fluid form'))">
        <div class="circle green-circle circle-position pull-left"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-plus color-white circle-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span>        </div>Добавить еще поля</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: [] only makes it an array on the server

Comment: @mplungjan Suppose, but I'm not sure. But how do I "split" my radio buttons that, they also considered an array?

Comment: Why do you want to make it an array? If a radio button group has same name, any one of them will be selected and that would become the value. It shouldn't be an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not find a native solution in HTML.

Therefore it was necessary to use such a solution to the JS:

```
$(this).closest('.container-fluid').find('.row:eq(0)').clone(true).find('input[type=radio]').attr('name', function(i, val){return val.replace(/(\d+)/, function(n){ return ++n })});
```

As a result, when you click on "duplicate field", appears radio buttons with the names: text-alignment[1], text-alignment[2]...